# I'm trying to place multiple paintComponents in a JFrame.

Tags: java, swing

Pressing Button 1 puts a box in pane2, pressing Button 2 puts another box up, but the 1st one disappears.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class GuiDemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    JFrame pane1 = new JFrame("pane1");
    JFrame pane2 = new JFrame("pane2");
    public  GuiDemo(){

        pane1.setSize(400,400);
        pane1.setLocation(100, 100);
        pane2.setSize(400,400);
        pane2.setLocation(800, 100);
        pane1.setVisible(true);
        pane2.setVisible(true);
        pane1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton b1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        pane1.add(b1);
        pane1.add(b2);
        b1.setVisible(true);
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b2.setVisible(true);
        b2.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        switch (e.getActionCommand()){
            case "Button 1":{
                placeCircle pc = new placeCircle(0);
                pane2.add(pc);
                pane2.setVisible(true);
                break;}
            case "Button 2":{
                placeCircle pc = new placeCircle(1);
                pane2.add(pc);
                pane2.setVisible(true);
                break;}
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         new GuiDemo();
    }

}
```

a is passed as the offset beteween box 1 and box 2.

```
class placeCircle extends JPanel{
    int a;
    public placeCircle(int a){
        this.a = a;

    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(20+a*100, 20, 20, 20);       
    }

}
```

but my main question is, should I be using painComponent?

Comment: Please consider using camel case with first letter capitalization for your class names, as this is the official [naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) in java!

Comment: Th basic answer is, don't do it this way, you're fighting the layout manager. Instead, you should have a single component/panel, which maintains a List of objects it needs to paint, and then in its paintComponent method, it iterates this list put paint them

Answer (score 2):

> Pressing Button 1 puts a box in pane2, pressing Button 2 puts another box up, but the 1st one disappears.

The default layout manager for a JFrame is the BorderLayout. You are adding components to the `CENTER` of the BorderLayout, but only a single components can be displayed at one time so you only see the last one.

> should I be using painComponent?

Yes, but all of your painting needs to be done in a single component in the paintComponent() method of that component.

So basically you need to keep a List of Objects to paint. Then the paintComponent() method iterates through the list and paints each object.

Check out the `Draw On Component` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). For an example of this approach.